# Find a certain column name in all views in one select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I'm searching for a certain column name in all views. I know that the following works for all tables but don't know how to do it for all views:

What I use to find a column_name='SHORT_TITLE' in all tables but now need to search all views:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE column_name='SHORT_TITLE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle:

Joining all_tab_columns with all_views

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM all_tab_columns, all_views
WHERE all_tab_columns.table_name = all_views.view_name
AND column_name = ...
```

Result of table_name will only be views

SQL:

We can do this by joining information_schema.views and information_schema.columns

```
SELECT v.table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.views v JOIN information_schema.columns c  
ON v. = c.table_schema 
AND v.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE column_name = ...
```

v.table_name is the name of the view.

EDIT: I added Oracle because I just realized the all_tab_columns in your question